# How to know which Implementation of Interface is being used?

Tags: java, interface

I've below code snippet.

```
public int appendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent event) {

    int size = 0;

    if (this.appenderList != null) {
        size = this.appenderList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Appender appender = (Appender) this.appenderList.elementAt(i);
            appender.doAppend(event);
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Here Appender is a Interface but when I check [the Appender's official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html), It is being implemented by so many classes.

I want to know, In such cases, How would I know which class's Implementation out of all classes who implements `Appender` Interface is getting used ?

For example in above code, How would I know `doAppend` is which class's implementation ?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? `interfaces` are there to hide the implementation and just expose official "api"

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to know the implementation? The benefit of interfaces is to decouple their delcaration from the (concrete) implementation. As an aside: `Appender appender = (Appender) this.appenderList.elementAt(i);` why do you need to cast here? Maybe you want to take another look at the definition of this list (especially its generic parameter).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `appender.getClass()` to see which actual type your appender has. You can also use the `instanceof` operator to test the type of an object.